# How can I create a build file through Ant script in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios4, ant

How can I create build files using ANT Script in iPhone SDK? If it is possible, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to call out to [xcodebuild](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html).  This will work, but doesn't give you *that* much control over the build. You still have to have an Xcode project for it to work.  Unless you have a lot of non-Xcode build steps to perform it doesn't buy you much over just invoking `xcodebuild` from a shell script.